# How to get react-navigation to behave the same on IOS and Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am using the Tab Navigator for navigation on my app, but it uses a different UI on IOS and Android. Is there any way to get it to behave the same way on both IOS and Android. Or can anybody recommend any other libraries aside from react navigation.

I'm trying to make my navigation similar to the instagram app (https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-images-plus1/instagram-ui-kit-kerroudj-1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-navigation` by default uses [`TabBarBottom`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/v1.5.11/src/views/TabView/TabBarBottom.js) for iOS and [`TabBarTop`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/v1.5.11/src/views/TabView/TabBarTop.js) for Android. If you want to use the same tabbar for both OS you can easily owerride this behavior with [`tabBarComponent`](https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig) property.

> **tabBarComponent** - Component to use as the tab bar, e.g. `TabBarBottom` (this is the default on iOS), `TabBarTop` (this is the
>   default on Android).

**Sample**

```
import  { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';

export default TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  }
);
```